# GET query through javascript with page reload, url rewriting problem

Tags: javascript, string, url-rewriting, get, search-engine

I use url rewriting on one of my projects, and I would like to be able to perform queries through a search box with javascript by, on a "type enter" event, grabbing the value of this search box and passing it through a GET request to another search page. The end result would be a search address a la twitter (ie mysite.com/search/mykeyword). My code is the following:

```
$("#search-box").keyup(function(event) {    
    var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (code == "13") { // ENTER
        var q = $(this).val();
        document.location.href = "/search/"+q;
    }
});
```

2 questions:

1. how can I sanitize the q string with JS to avoid having a non url encoded string with spaces or special characters? (of course it doesn't work if i type any of these values). I tried the function escape but it still doesn't work.
2. is it a good idea to perform a GET query this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use escape.  Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

   `var q = encodeURIComponent($(this).val());`
2. Perfectly fine... although I wouldn't use URL rewriting on the parameters to a search.

Comment: weird... even though it encodes the url (http://localhost:8888/search/test%20url), it throws a 404 error.

Comment: What would you use to perform the search instead of URL rewriting?

Comment: the url rewrite rule for my search is: RewriteRule ^search/([a-z]+)$     /search.php?q=$1

Comment: works with no space/special character/upper case, but not with any of them!

Comment: I'd just say /search/?query=test%20url .  Not only is there no reason to have a fixed-endpoint in a text search, this just causes URL cruft for crawlers like Google.  Your URL rewrite rule isn't generic enough.  Try this:  RewriteRule ^search/(.*) /app/controllers/page/search/search.php?q=$1